# How to host a custom font on Google Drive (non Google Font) for use on Blogger

Tags: blogger, fonts

This is related to the following:

1. [Hosting on google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924180/hosting-on-google-drive)
2. [how to import webfonts in blogger from google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484511/how-to-import-webfonts-in-blogger-from-google-drive)
3. [Can I use google fonts in Google Drive web hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005695/can-i-use-google-fonts-in-google-drive-web-hosting)

But 1 is about hosting a static web page; 2 is about Google Fonts, and the comment by @abhay9455 to Google’s documentation does not help; and 3 was about Google Fonts, which is already well covered by both Blogger and Google Web Font implementation. What I would like to do, is use a font I created on [Calligraphr](https://www.calligraphr.com/) for a post I am working on; this is not a professional font, and thus is not hosted by anyone but me. My only source for hosting files online is Google Drive. How can I use this font in a Blogger post when I have hosted it publicly on Google Drive?

My code for fetching the font is this:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Tolvtalsystem';
    src: url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/163bhcNTENeBtF1wPhykqOTlKPZud7xAG')
         format('opentype');
}
</style>
```

The font does not load. (I uninstalled it locally to make sure I would know whether it loaded or not.) What do I need to do to be able to have it loaded from my Google Drive? As for now, I think the solution might be in getting a link that actually identifies it as a font (a link ending in .otf), but I have no idea how to get this.

Comment: Can you not upload any fonts to Blogger? How do you deal with other files like images?

Comment: I just tested if I could cheat my way through it with the image upload function. It won’t upload none-image files (‘Upload failed. Server denied.’)

Comment: "I think the solution might be in getting a link that actually identifies it as a font" - certainly the link you are using doesn't actually return a "font file" at all. It returns a 302 redirect response (since you appear to be missing a trailing slash), followed by another 302 to append `edit`, followed by a `text/html` response. "a link ending in .otf" - not only that, but Google Drive would need to also respond with the appropriate mime-type (it needs to "host" the file).

Comment: I would be surprised if this is possible, since [Google disabled web hosting support](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html) back in August 2016. And you'd need "web hosting support" in order to correctly serve a font-file. So, Q1 and Q3 you link to are no longer possible anyway. Q2 is actually about "web fonts", not "Google Fonts" (so it's really the same as what you are asking here), except the answer to that question would seem to be a bit wrong (and out of date)?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-css-js-returns-404-error

Comment: @MrWhite It appears this means this is impossible. Would it be uncalled for to edit the question to allow for other options to achieve the same result (free online services that allows you to host files which can be called by websites)?

Answer (score 3):

You can grab the actual download link (see this reddit post) https://www.reddit.com/r/tabletopsimulator/comments/38h598/hosting_files_with_google_drive/

Basically, put the file id into the direct download link: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID`

this is the direct download link for any file! I tested it out in carrd (using the embed feature) and this link used as the source worked, this is very very late but I thought id contribute. I'm not sure if it'll host on blogger properly but it's possible!

Comment: Excellent contribution. I will try it out today. Can you edit your answer so it is self-contained? Answers on SE should not require the reader to open a link to see the answer; using links to show sources, however, is of course good form. So in short: If you write the relevant information from the Reddit post into your answer, it is gold.